# windows phone 8 - Map thumbnail

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, maps

I'd like to display a small image from the map fixed over a given location and if the user taps the map I'd like to navigate to different page with a large map control (just like in the HERE maps app when you're looking at a place's information). 
So I'd like to disable every interaction with the map control (like pan, zoom, etc.) but I need know when it's tapped, so disabling the control won't work. 
I tried using a small map control

```
<maps:Map Height="100" Width="100" x:Name="Map" Tap="Map_Tap" >
```

but I couldn't find a way to achieve the desired result with it.

Could you suggest something for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the general approach...

Place a **transparent** rectangle on top of your Map control. This should cause gesture recognition to be handled by the rectangle rather than the Map.

In a tap handler for your rectangle, navigate to the next page.

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Transparent" Tap="Map_Tap"/>
    <maps:Map Height="100" Width="100" x:Name="Map" >
</Grid>
```

*Disclaimer: I haven't tested this code yet, but I think it should work!*

Hope it helps.

Comment: In fact I did the same thing except I used a canvas because it wouldn't work with the rectangle for some reason, yet it feels sort of messy. I mean I thought there must have been a cleaner way to do this. It works though.

Comment: @Peter strange, I was trying to do something similar, but for me the rectangle works not the canvas

Comment: You need to make sure that you actually specify `Fill="Transparent"`, otherwise I believe the hit testing is simply skipped for the Rectangle... Maybe this was why it did not work for a Rectangle? Not sure about the Canvas though.